# \maketitle output invading text

Tags: xetex, titles, two-column

I'm trying to create a class to typeset a government gazette. this is the [template](http://www.mesquita.rj.gov.br/pmm/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/PUBLICA%C3%87%C3%83O-DIA-22-de-setembro-de-2017.pdf) I'm following, although I don't care about all the colours.

I'm using the `article` class as a baseline (with the twocolumn option on), `fancyhdr` to make the header and footer, except for the first page, where I'm trying to redefine maketitle to a header-like structure, similar to the template (it doesn't have to be fancy, the logo and the text in black and white would suffice).

my problem is that the title created by the `\maketitle`
 command is invading the text in the second column, as is ignoring the rule that separates the columns, as in:

[image]

is there a way of making the title more similar to the linked PDF above?

I've based my class mostly in the `newspaper` package. here is the class code:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{doliberto}[2017/09/21 Mesquita's D.O. class]

% 
%% load article class with options
\LoadClass[twocolumn, a4paper, 10pt]{article}

% pass unused options to article
\DeclareOption{onecolumn}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

%
%% package loading
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage[portuges]{datetime2}
\RequirePackage{datetime2-calc}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}

% brazilian portuguese support in XeLaTeX
\setmainlanguage{portuges}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

%
%% variables

% counters
\newcounter{issue}
\newcommand\currentissue[1]{\setcounter{issue}{#1}}
\newcounter{month}
\newcommand\currentmonth[1]{\setcounter{month}{#1}}
\newcounter{year}
\newcommand\currentyear[1]{\setcounter{year}{#1}}
\newcounter{day}
\newcommand\currentday[1]{\setcounter{day}{#1}}

% date
\newcommand{\dataextenso}{\arabic{day} de \DTMportugesmonthname{\arabic{month}} de \arabic{year}}

% whose D.O.
\renewcommand{\@author}{Prefeitura Municipal de Mesquita}
\newcommand{\@email}{anexogabinete@mesquita.rj.gov.br}
\newcommand{\@site}{http://www.mesquita.rj.gov.br/}
\newcommand{\@location}{Mesquita}

%
%% text dimensions (for now, defaults from newspaper package)
\setlength\topmargin{-48pt} % article default = -58pt
%\setlength\headheight{0pt} % article default = 12pt
\setlength\headsep{34pt} % article default = 25pt
\setlength\marginparwidth{-20pt} % article default = 121pt
\setlength\textwidth{504pt} % article default = 418pt
\setlength\textheight{684pt} % article default = 296pt
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-30pt}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
\setlength{\headheight}{5cm}
\lhead{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{prefeitura-mesquita.jpg}}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{{\footnotesize \url{\@site}}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{{\footnotesize \href{mailto:\@email}{\@email}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%\thispagestyle{firststyle}
\vspace*{-40pt}
\begin{center}
{\setlength\fboxsep{3mm}\raisebox{12pt}{\framebox[1.2\width]{\parbox[c]{1.15in}{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{prefeitura-mesquita.jpg}}}}}\hfill%
{\huge Diário Oficial}\hfill%   
\raisebox{12pt}{\textbf{\footnotesize \@author}}\\
\vspace*{0.1in}
\rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\
{\small {\small\@location, \dataextenso} \hfill \textbf{Diário Oficial Nº \arabic{issue}}}\\
\rule[6pt]{\textwidth}{1.2pt}
\end{center}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{{\small\@location, \dataextenso}}
\chead{\textbf{Diário Oficial Nº \arabic{issue}}}
\rhead{{\small \@author}}
\lfoot{{\footnotesize \url{\@site}}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{{\footnotesize \href{mailto:\@email}{\@email}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

%\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

%
%% DOli macros

%% this must be in .tex file
% \titleformat*{\section}[block]{\large\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}

%% macros

% título do ato
\newcommand\headline[1]{\begin{center} {\bfseries \MakeUppercase{#1}} \end{center} \par}
% quem assina
\newcommand\byline[2]{\begin{center} {\bfseries \MakeUppercase{#1}} \\%
            {\small\bfseries #2} \\ %
            \rule[3pt]{0.4\hsize}{0.5pt}\\ \end{center} \par}
% separando seções de cada secretaria
\newcommand\closearticle{{\begin{center}\rule[6pt]{\hsize}{1pt}\vspace*{-16pt}
      \rule{\hsize}{0.5pt}\end{center}}}
```

MWE:

```
%% needs xelatex to compile!
%% you can choose your tex engine on sharelatex/overleaf, or
%% (preferrable) download TeXlive!
\documentclass{doliberto}
\currentissue{4}
\currentmonth{11}
\currentyear{1994}
\currentday{28}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Secretaria Municipal de Educação}

\headline{Portaria Nº 394/2017} 

\Blindtext     

\byline{Thaís dos Santos Lima}{Secretário Municipal de Educação}

\closearticle

\section{Conselho Municipal da Criança e do Adolescente}

\headline{RESOLUÇÃO CMDCA Nº 003 / 2017.}

\Blindtext

\byline{Jacqueline  Freitas}{\quad}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hint: You can use the `blindtext` package to generate fill text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\maketitle` inside a `minipage` to make it stay within the column width.

```
\begin{minipage}{.9\columnwidth}%
\maketitle
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

---

or to have the title span the whole page follow the suggestion of [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393209/maketitle-output-invading-text/393211#comment977022_393211):

```
\twocolumn[\maketitle]
```

[image]

---

Alternatively if the changes should happen in the `.sty` file:

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%\thispagestyle{firststyle}
\twocolumn[{
\vspace*{-40pt}
\begin{center}
{\setlength\fboxsep{3mm}\raisebox{12pt}{\framebox[1.2\width]{\parbox[c]{1.15in}{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{example-image}}}}}\hfill%
{\huge Diário Oficial}\hfill%   
\raisebox{12pt}{\textbf{\footnotesize \@author}}\\
\vspace*{0.1in}
\rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\
{\small {\small\@location, \dataextenso} \hfill \textbf{Diário Oficial Nº \arabic{issue}}}\\
\rule[6pt]{\textwidth}{1.2pt}
\end{center}
}]
}
```

Comment: that looks good! thanks!

can I do something similar to get the title to span both columns?

Comment: the minipage is just essentially being used to redefine \textwidth here I think

Comment: @brunocuconato yes the standard `article` `\maketitle` already spans both columns, see in `article.cls` just make `\maketitle` do `\twocolumn[\@maketitle]%`  wheer `\@maketitke` is your main title code.

Comment: thanks for the help! that's what I wanted :) as I understand, and @David Carlisle pointed out, \maketitle should be on two columns already, so why do we need to use this? (but again, it works great!)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks a lot for your comment! I included your suggestion into my answer and removed the superfluous `\begin{@twocolumnfalse}...` If you would like to edit your own answer and include it there, I going to revert my edit.

Comment: No need for you to revert (I wasn't planning on adding to my answer)  although what I suggested really is as in `article` class the user document should just have `\maketitle`, the class code should use `\twocolumn[{... the existing code ..}]`

Comment: @brunocuconato the standard article `\maketitle` spans two columsn but you redefined it not to do that, you need to use the form using `\twocolumn` in your definition of `\maketitle`

Comment: oh, ok. I forgot about the redefinition.. I tried using `\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\twocolumn[...code...]}` but it throws some error about an excessive curly brace. using it on the document works fine, though. any idea why?

Comment: @brunocuconato See the comment of David Carlisle above: you need `\twocolumn[{...}]` -- pay attention to the curly bracket inside the square one.

Comment: oh, I thought the curly braces were not mandatory, as I'd never seen this syntax. is it so that we can have a multi-line argument? as in `\twocolumn[\maketitle]` we didn't have to use the curly braces..

thank you both very much :)

Answer (score 4):

```
\rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\
```

makes a rule that is `\textwidth` wide (that is, it will span both columns) you presumably intended `\columnwidth`